# Python HTTP POST request

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm currently trying to send a HTTP POST via requests library in Python to a remote server to validate a serial number. I've already accomplished this with the following script:

**validate-request.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
print "\r\n"

r = requests.post("https://xx.xx.xx.xx/cgi-bin/verify.py", data={'serial':'XXXXXXX')}, verify=True)
```

This already works great. When the serial number is validated, I would really like it to respond by offering a download and/or possibly text accompanied with it. I'm currently only able to validate the serial (the actual script is much longer as it fetches it from MySQL, so this is a simpler version.)

**validate.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
serial = form.getvalue('serial')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<b>SERIAL OK</b></br>"

if serial == "XXXXXXX":
    print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print "SERIAL <b>OK</b></br>"
else:
    print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print "SERIAL <b>NOT OK</b></br>"
```

What I would also like to include is returning some extra information (text, mainly) and possibly offering a file to download.

This means, on the **validate-request.py**, I would have to play with the r.text it returns. Is there perhaps a way to scan the return text to find what I'm looking for? Also, how would I go about offering the file from **validate.py** and how would I go about accepting it from **validate-request.py**?

Comment: Would you will use json format for response?

Comment: @DmitryKalinin If it's a solution I would definitely consider it! Do you have an idea?

Comment: for example https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-data-using-python--cms-25758

Comment: @user5740843, if response content-type is `text/html` then `JSON` is definitely not what you're looking for. If you need to parse `HTML` response you need to use `Beautiful soup`. This might be useful for you http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html